# How to prove that two parametrizations of a surface M give the same tangent plane

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

If you have 2 parametrizations of a surface $M$, $x$ and $y$, such that for some point $P \in M$, $x(u_0,v_0)=y(s_0,t_0)=P$. How do you show that the tangent plane of $M$ at $P$ are the same? That is how do I show that $\text{Span}(x_u,x_v)=\text{Span}(y_s,y_t)$.

Comment: Try to prove that the definition of the tangent plane for any local parametrization is equivalent to "the set of all tangent vectors of all curves through that point". Then you are independent of which local param. you choose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: Write $x(u,v)=y(s(u,v),t(u,v))$ and use the chain rule to show that $x_u$ and $x_v$ (evaluated at $(u_0,v_0)$) are linear combinations of $y_s$ and $y_t$ (evaluated at $(s_0,t_0)$). This shows $\text{Span}(x_u,x_v)\subset\text{Span}(y_s,y_t)$. Now what?

Answer (score 0):

Ted Shifrin's answer can be generalized:

Let $A$ be an affine space with a real and normed translation space $V$ and let $x\colon U\subset\mathbf{R}^n\to A$ and $y\colon U'\subset\mathbf{R}^n\to A$ be injective maps defined on open subsets of $\mathbf{R}^n$ such that the transition maps $t:=y^{-1}\circ x\colon U\cap U'\to U\cap U'$ and $t^{-1}=x^{-1}\circ y\colon U\cap U'\to U\cap U'$ are differentiable in $a\in U\cap U'$ and $b:=y^{-1}(x(a))\in U\cap U'$. Finally, we require that $x$ and $y$ are differentiable in $a$ and $b$, respectively*.

In this case, $Dt(a)\colon\mathbf{R}^n\to\mathbf{R}^n$ and $Dt^{-1}(b)\colon\mathbf{R}^n\to\mathbf{R}^n$ are isomorphisms inverse to each other** and according to the chain rule,
\begin{equation}
Dy(b)=Dx(a)\circ Dt^{-1}(b)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
Dx(a)=Dy(b)\circ Dt(a).
\end{equation}
Thus, $Dx(a)(\mathbf{R}^n)=Dy(b)(\mathbf{R}^n)=:S\subset V$.

In your notation,
\begin{equation}
x_i=\lim\nolimits_{\delta\to 0}\frac{x(a_1,\ldots,a_{i-1},a_i+\delta,a_{i+1},\ldots,a_n)-x(a_1,\ldots,a_n)}{\delta}=Dx(a)(e_i)
\end{equation}
and $\text{span}\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}=S$.*** Thus, we just proved the result you asked for.

**Remark**: $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is a basis of $S$ if and only if $Dx(a)$ is injective and because of the two centered equations, $Dx(a)$ is injective if and only if $Dy(b)$ is injective.

*If $X$ and $Y$ are affine spaces with real and normed translation spaces $V$ and $W$, a map $f\colon D\subset X\to Y$ is called differentiable in $p\in D$, if $p$ is an inner point of $D$, $f$ is continuous in $p$ and a linear map $A\colon V\to W$ with the following property exsits: For each $0<\epsilon$, there is a $0<\delta$ such that
\begin{equation}
\|f(p+v)-f(p)-A(v)\|\leq\epsilon\|v\|
\end{equation}
for all $v\in V$ with $\|v\|<\delta$. If $f$ is differentiable in $p$, there is a unique linear map with this property, called the derivative of $Df(p)$ of $f$ in $p$.

**You can prove this by using the chain rule and the fact that a map $f\colon A\to B$ is injective if and only if there is a map $g\colon B\to A$ such that $g\circ f=\text{id}_A$ and surjective if and only if there is a map $g\colon B\to A$ such that $f\circ g=\text{id}_B$.

*** If $f\colon D\subset\mathbf{R}^n\to A$ is differentiable in $a=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in D$, the partial derivatives
\begin{equation}
\partial_i f(a)=\lim\nolimits_{\delta\to 0}\frac{x(a_1,\ldots,a_{i-1},a_i+\delta,a_{i+1},\ldots,a_n)-x(a_1,\ldots,a_n)}{\delta}\in V
\end{equation}
exist for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and
\begin{equation}
Df(a)(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\cdot \partial_i f(a).
\end{equation}